# How to track down strange crashes of iPad app in AQClient thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

My app recently started to show strange crashes I'm unable to track down to the source. Any help of what to look for would be helpful :)

Crash logs from the device (an iOS 5 iPad) shows the following stuff at the beginning:

```
Date/Time:       2011-11-08 19:07:21.044 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x406cad3d
Crashed Thread:  9
```

The crashed thread 9 is a `AQClient` thread and its stack trace looks like this:

```
Thread 9 name:  AQClient
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30107fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   AVFoundation                    0x3420cdc8 _ZL27AudioPlayerAQOutputCallbackPvP16OpaqueAudioQueueP16AudioQueueBuffer + 28
2   AudioToolbox                    0x32a409fe ClientMessageHandler::OutputBufferComplete(unsigned int) + 98
3   AudioToolbox                    0x32a425d6 AQClientCallbackMessageReader::DispatchCallbacks(unsigned char*, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int) + 198
4   AudioToolbox                    0x32a408dc AQCallbackReceiver_CallbackNotificationsAvailable + 364
5   AudioToolbox                    0x329ee4b6 _XCallbackNotificationsAvailable + 54
6   AudioToolbox                    0x329e436c mshMIGPerform + 368
7   CoreFoundation                  0x34fa454c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
8   CoreFoundation                  0x34fa44ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
9   CoreFoundation                  0x34fa333c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
10  CoreFoundation                  0x34f264d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34f2639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  AudioToolbox                    0x32a3d29c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 116
13  AudioToolbox                    0x329c5aac CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35756c16 _pthread_start + 314
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35756ad0 thread_start + 0
```

This seems to be related to AVAudioPlayer or MPMoviePlayer activity. In the app I have a movie playing (.m4v from app's bundle), then when it's finished the view flips to the side without the movie and audio starts playing.

In the case of crashes what I can hear is the same audio playing twice, even it's not intended. Then upon finishing the audio (when the AVAudioPlayer should be deallocated) the app crashes.

I added some `NSLog`s to app to track down what's happening here. The console at the critical point showed me such a thing:

```
Nov  8 19:17:19 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: Finished movie
Nov  8 19:17:19 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: Finished movie
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: flipping
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: flipping
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: --> dealloc <AVAudioPlayer: 0x6887530> (d2_s3_l3_q9.aif)
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown XXX[1753] <Warning>: --> dealloc <AVAudioPlayer: 0x6887530> (d2_s3_l3_q9.aif)
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x68859f0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x11ef30 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x1a6720 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x6872400 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

(...) 

Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x6872ed0 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x10cf80 of class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x6850480 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x10a530 of class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x1d15d0 of class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x6884550 of class TFCrashHandler autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x685ec10 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:20 unknown UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432][1753] <Notice>: objc[1753]: Object 0x6856270 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Nov  8 19:17:21 unknown com.apple.networkd[1763] <Notice>: main:212 networkd.1763 built Sep 16 2011 00:02:59
Nov  8 19:17:25 unknown ReportCrash[1764] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process XXX[1753]
Nov  8 19:17:25 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.bundle.name[0x2432]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  8 19:17:25 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'XXX' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  8 19:17:25 unknown ReportCrash[1764] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/XXX_2011-11-08-191724_iKotapad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

EDIT:

The key part here, I think, is the doubled logs at the beginning. When non-crashing, it shows up once only. And, the problem could come from calling the `dealloc` method of the same object twice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say take care of that `autorelease` pool leak first and see if the problem remains.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with autorelease pool in non-main thread, and since I don't do any multithread things in this app and I don't use background tasks - I think it can be a problem not in my code...

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be related to me using nonatomic properties in my code. Maybe this could have caused the doubled access to the variable?

Comment: Console seems to indicate that the code starting your audio is running twice, but is referencing the same object, which works great until it comes time to dealloc it.  Comment out one of the places you're starting the audio, even if you think it's the only place, and see if it gets called twice.  It's possible that the event that is triggered at the end of the movie is getting called twice and so the audio is starting twice as a result - try adding a boolean flag to ensure the audio start routine only runs once.

Comment: Messing with `nonatomic` may clear the symptomatic crash but won't stop the issue of the audio playing twice.

Comment: I already have kind of this in my code... I play there multiple audio files, one after another. I have audio files in an array and I have a index of currently playing sound in an instance variable. So, if this method that calls the actual sound playing, would be called twice in normal conditions, it should play different audio files, not the same one...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with an iPhone app running in the iOS5 simulator.  Apparently, with this set up, if you have an autoreleased object without an autorelease pool defined, the system will release that object immediately and print out that message: "...Object 0x6872ed0 of class TheClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug".  In my code, it was releasing the object even before the variable assignment, so I was guaranteed to have bad memory after that line.  To fix, you need to supply an autorelease pool...you can wrap the code that allocates those objects (at whatever level is appropriate) with @autoreleasepool{ ... }, e.g.:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:myBytes length:myLength];
    //do something with data
}
```

By defining the autorelease pool with @autoreleasepool, it will keep that data object around (not try and release it) while you then use that object.

Another solution would be to allocate the objects that are being freed using a method that does not use autorelease.  I know with NSData, [NSData data] will return an autoreleased object whereas [[NSData alloc] init] will not.  There are likely analogues with the objects you're using.  This is obviously only a possibility if you control the allocation...if not, you are likely stuck defining an autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

This might only happen in the simulator. I've experienced a similar issue which I could not fix, but found out that it happens only in simulator, runs fine on all devices.